# Encrypt zip file while uploading to media library folder sitecore 8.2

Tags: sitecore-client, media-library, sitecore-api, pipelines

i have followed the sitecore [link](https://sdn.sitecore.net/articles/media/prevent%20files%20from%20uploading/pipeline%20upload.aspx) and create my custom processor for (Sitecore.Pipelines.Upload.Save). i have faced issues while saving all media items.
it gives error on `file.SaveAs(filename);`

> Error message : "Could not find a part of the path
>   'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\demosite\Website\{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}\{3D6658D8-A0BF-4E75-B3E2-D050FABCF4E1}\{730C1699-87A4-4CA7-A9CE-294AD7151F13}_blog-banner.jpg'.

can anyone help how i can encrypt zip file using SHA-256 while uploading into media library through content editor under specific folder and save it.